# React JS - Value is not passing to the element from App.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

im starting to study React JS, so I`m trying to build an app that makes cotation and I`m trying to pass the cotation value as a prop.

But it doesn work. Please help!

Thanks!!

```
import './App.css';
import RealDolar from './components/real_dolar.js';

function App() {
  let realDolar = 0;
  let url = 'https://api.freecurrencyapi.com/v1/latest?base_currency=USD&currencies=BRL&apikey=xyz';
  fetch(url).then(res=>{
    return res.json()
  }).then(json=>{
    realDolar = json['data']['BRL'];
  })
  return (
    <div className="Real_Rapido">
      <RealDolar cotacao={realDolar} />
    </div>
  );
}
export default App;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

worked with this..

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import RealDolar from './components/real_dolar.js';
import './App.css';

function App(props) {
   const [realDolar, setRealDolar] = useState()

  const fetchDolar = async () => {
    const url = "https://api.freecurrencyapi.com/v1/latest?base_currency=USD&currencies=BRL&apikey=xyz"
    const res = await fetch(url)
    const {data} = await res.json()
    const {BRL} = data

    setRealDolar({ BRL })
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchDolar()
  }, [])

  if (realDolar == null) return <div>Loading</div>

  return (
    <div className="Real_Rapido">
      <RealDolar cotacao={realDolar['BRL']}/>
      <Informacoes />
    </div>
  )
}

export default App

// RealDolar  Component
function RealDolar({cotacao}) {
  // use cotacao here
  // ... 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Hi! You need to use `useState` and `useEffect` hooks.

Learn more about hooks: https://react.dev/reference/react/useState and https://react.dev/reference/react/useEffect

```js
import './App.css';
import RealDolar from './components/real_dolar.js';
    
function App() {
  const [realDolar, setRealDolar] = useState(0);
  const url = 'https://api.freecurrencyapi.com/v1/latest? 
  base_currency=USD&currencies=BRL&apikey=xyz';

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch(url).then(res=>{
      return res.json()
    }).then(json=>{
      setRealDolar(json['data']['BRL']);
    })
  }, [])
     
  return (
    <div className="Real_Rapido">
      <RealDolar cotacao={realDolar} />
      </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Hi guy, its kind work... but, just some times... its kind start page with value 0, and even i got the value, it already had called the components with the value of prop = 0. Does have a way that I could tell the component wait to be started, i dont know, something like that

Comment: You can add conditional rendering. Like { realDolar == 0 ? '' : <RealDolar cotacao={realDolar} /> }

Comment: Or { realDolar && <RealDolar cotacao={realDolar} /> }

Answer (score 0):

The passed prop should be a state:

```js
function App() {
  const [realDolar, setRealDolar] = useState(0);
  useEffect(() => {
    let url = 'https://api.freecurrencyapi.com/v1/latest?base_currency=USD&currencies=BRL&apikey=xyz';
    fetch(url).then(res=>{
      return res.json()
    }).then(json=>{
      setRealDolar(json['data']['BRL'])
    })
  }, [])
  return (
    <div className="Real_Rapido">
      <RealDolar cotacao={realDolar} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Just a word of caution: `.then(json`: at this stage it's no longer JSON so it might be a good idea to rename the variable.

Comment: Hi guy, its kind work... but, just some times... its kind start page with value 0, and even i got the value, it already had called the components with the value of prop = 0. Does have a way that I could tell the component wait to be started, i dont know, something like that.